# What is Deveikut (clinging to God)?

Tags: words, mesilas-yesharim, deveikut

In chapter 1 of the Mesilat Yesharim (Path of the Just), the author writes:

"When you look further into the matter, you will see that true perfection is only clinging to God".

What does "clinging to God" mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

#### You asks for an answer from the Ramchal itself.

See Derech Hashem chapter II:

> "‏ג. ואמנם, מלבד היות הבריה הזאת שקנתה השלימות ראויה לידבק בבוראהוכפי מה שירבה בשלימויות, כך הוא מרבה האחיזה וההתדבקות בו, עד שבהגיעו אל חכלית קניית השלימות, הנה הוא מגיע אל תכלית האחיזה וההתדבקות בו יתברך, ונמצא מתדבק בו יתברך ונהנה בטובו ומשתלם בו, והוא עצמו בעל טובו ושלימותו:  ‏"

Striving for perfection.

#### But

I think that for the Ramchal dvekut is in this snippet in **chapter 1 of MESILAT YESHARIM**

> ולשבור כל המחיצות המפסיקות בינו לבין קונו, הן הנה כל עניני החומריות והתלוי בהם

To break all the screens separating him from his creator. I.E. material interests, i.e. bad midoth. to go on messilat yesharim.

Comment: I'm not clear from either of those quotes exactly what devekut means. how do you learn it?

Comment: The first quote is sayimg what is dvekut
The second is a more subjective-practical purpose. I feel that a lot of things separate me from my creator, from the truth etc. My life is dedicated to break the screens. It is the way to dvekut. For me this statement is perhaps the greeter of the book.

Comment: how did you understand that. i don't. thanks

Comment: dvekut is a lake of obstacle. no fusion, but a synchronization with the retson H. Many things are obstacle, taava, kin'a. and because I suffer from these I can not adhere to retson H. I am not specialist @ray but I hope that we will understand something together.

Answer (score 0):

In Tanya it talks about varying levels of fear and love of Gd from the simple Jew who have a natural fear and love that aren't revealed and on the other spectrum the love and fear of of the righteous. Those who are righteous are able to attain the higher levels of love and fear of Hashem. Deveikus can be understood as the attachment of love and fear that righteous people have for Gd. The sages ask, how can one cleave to Hashem? By attaching oneself to a tzaddik and learning from their ways one is cleaves to Hashem. By having faith in a tzaddik especially one who can be considered a leader if that generation. Also, there is a verse in Torah which refers to this idea that we say everyday in pesuke d'Zimbra, "and they believed in Hashem and Moses His servant".

This is the beginning stages of developing a sense of deveikus as elsewhere in chadsidus it is discussed that one may not just rely on a tzaddik to do for you but only they are there to help you in connecting to Gd by pointing you in a specific direction in one's Avoidas Hashem.

Comment: thanks but was asking in the context of the ramchal quote.

Comment: dvekus is adherence. to adhere the main purpose is to destroy obstacles that obstruct the way

Comment: Yeah, just not as familiar with the ramchal but was hoping this may be at least somewhat helpful